# Lubuntu updatedb.locate may scap bind mounted nfs file systems

Tags: mount, cron, nfs, find

I noticed that `cron.daily` that run `updatedb.locate` was talking very long to complete (if ever completing).  I have interrupted last run with find taking more than 16 hours of CPU time.

After investigating it a bit, I figured out that find was indexing huge nfs mounted files system.  Despite the fact that nfs is listed as one of the file systems should be skipped in `PRUNEFS` `/etc/updatedb.conf` as well as in `PRUNEFS` in `/etc/cron.daily/locate` itself:

```
illia@illia-vm1:~$ grep PRUNEFS /etc/cron.daily/locate 
PRUNEFS="NFS nfs nfs4 afs binfmt_misc proc smbfs autofs iso9660 ncpfs coda devpts ftpfs devfs mfs shfs sysfs cifs lustre_lite tmpfs usbfs udf ocfs2"
export FINDOPTIONS PRUNEFS PRUNEPATHS NETPATHS LOCALUSER
```

It turned out that if a file system is bind mounted elsewhere, find will not see its actual type, but instead will treat it has having type 'none':

```
illia@illia-vm1:~$ mount | grep /shared
/shared on /var/lib/schroot/mount/<cut>/shared type none (ro,bind)
<cut>:/shared on /shared type nfs (ro,intr,soft,tcp,bg,nordirplus,addr=<cut>)

illia@illia-vm1:~$ find /shared -printf "%F %p\n"
none /shared
none /shared/<cut>
none /shared/<cut>
none /shared/<cut>
none /shared/<cut>
...
```

I was able to find a rather old Debian bug discussing this issue:

http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?func=detailitem&item_id=14921
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=329385

I can fix it for myself by adding "none" to `PRUNEFS` in `/etc/updatedb.conf` and creating `/etc/updatedb.findutils.cron.local` that would also add "none" to `PRUNEFS`.

I was wondering what would be the right action here?
It seems that Debian bug just states that the issue is there and `find` better be fixed.
I guess as there is a workaround the bug was not really bothering anyone too much.
I do not know if the workaround is in the Debian distribution, but it seems to be absent from Lubuntu (and Ubuntu I guess).
What should I do to have that workaround applied to Ubuntu systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to [file a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and once you have a bugtracking number, [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and ask whether anyone else has this problem and ask them to file a bug against your bug so that it "affects multiple users" and then it will be solved (probably by putting "none" in `PRUNEFS` as a standard...

**Fair warning:** filing a bug is a lot of work, so that's why everyone that found out about this (including me), has just shrugged his shoulders, corrected it on their own system and moved on. You need a lot of data for this bug to affect you, so you're probably running a server...  My solution was to shrug my shoulders and delete all the NTFS partitions after copying them over to EXT4...